# Adding additional source file to autoconf C++ project

Tags: autoconf

I tried to add additional source file in FDK-AAC. But when I autoconf and configure for the compilation, my source file didn't get compiled. Any idea how to make autoconf to include my source file in compilation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. For those who have the same problem as mine, the thing is there is the template `Makefile.am` which is used by `automake`. You just need to include your source file in the Makefile.am to get it compiled by generated `Makefile`.
Problem solved.